# Proving that an algorithm is deadlock-free

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, synchronization, deadlock

I found this algorithm:

```
sem empty = 1; 
sem full = 0;

public void send() { 
    P(empty)
    <<inserting data>> 
    V(full)
}

public T receive(){ 
    T data;
    P(full)
    <<data = extract()>> 
    V(empty);
    return data;
}
```

To demonstrate that it is deadlock-free, the author of the book has wrote this demonstration:
**-Hypothesis for absurd:**
(, ) = 0 → (, ) = (, ) + 1
(, ) = 0 → (, ) = (, )
**-Then we can say that:**
(, ) = (, ) + 1 = () + 1 = () + 1 = () + 1 → () = () + 1 → 0 = 1.

Can you help me understand why he repeated the line () + 1 = () + 1? Is it an error or does it have substituted something that didn't affect the value?
If the value of the semaphore **full** would have been more than 0, should he had to put a different value than +1?

Comment: I think that that equals sign is supposed to be an arrow.

Comment: @ruakh So it should be (, ) = (, ) + 1 = () + 1 → () + 1 = () + 1 → () = () + 1 → 0 = 1 ?

Comment: That's what I meant, yes; but I now realize that that doesn't make much sense. So, no clue.